# how to open simulate build open in iphone 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on my project and I'm facing simulator build issue for facebook review of application.

Simulator build is not opening in iPhone 5..

Kindly help with this issue. And process of how to build in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Select simulator iphone 5 by click on already selected simulator this will pop up all simulator list as shown in below.

[image]